# ¿Cómo proteger las credenciales de acceso de mi servidor en PHP?

Tags: php, seguridad

He realizado una clase PHP para descargar archivos desde un servidor FTP y me funciona, pero mi dilema es que dentro de la clase PHP tengo la IP_HOST, Puertos, Usuarios, ¿cómo podría ocultarlos para no dejarlos dentro de la clase? ¿Cómo puedo generar algo de seguridad y proteger las credenciales de acceso de mi servidor en PHP?

Ésta es mi clase PHP:

```
 $nombre_archivo = $_GET['archivo'];
 $destino = $_GET['ruta'];

 $local_file = 'C:/' . $nombre_archivo;
 $server_file = $destino . '/' . $nombre_archivo;
 $ftp_server = "MY IP SERVER";
 $ftp_usuario = "MY FTP USER";
 $ftp_pass = "MY FTP PASS";

 $con_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
 $lr = ftp_login($con_id, $ftp_usuario, $ftp_pass);

 if ((!$con_id) || (!$lr)) {
     echo 'ERROR DE CONEXION AL SERVIDOR ';
 } else {
     if (ftp_get($con_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
         echo 'ARCHIVO DESCARGADO CORRECTAMENTE ';
     } else {
         echo 'ERROR EN LA DESCARGA DEL ARCHIVO ';
     }
     ftp_close($con_id);
 }

 header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $nombre_archivo);
 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($local_file));
 readfile($local_file);
```

Lo mismo ocurre con mi clase database.php donde tengo la IP, puerto, usuario y clave de la base de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones para proteger las credenciales, que pasan por tenerlas en un fichero aparte que luego se leerá con PHP. Ese directorio puede estar:

- Dentro de la raíz del servidor web y protegido de acceso externo usando `.htaccess` o similares.
- Fuera de la raíz del servidor web y por tanto no accesibles para usuarios externos.

La segunda opción es mejor porque los usuarios externos no tienen acceso a las carpetas que están fuera de la raíz del servidor (no pueden accederse simplemente poniendo una dirección en la barra del navegador). Con la primera opción, si algo fallara en el servidor, los ficheros de credenciales podrían verse expuestos al público.

Entonces puedes sacar las credenciales fuera del directorio raíz, y las páginas PHP que las necesiten pueden referenciar y abrir ficheros dentro de la estructura del servidor (ya estén en la carpeta pública o fuera de ella).

Así por ejemplo, podrías tener una estructura simple como ésta:

```
/Aplicacion
   |- credenciales.ini
/Publico
   |- index.php
   |- /imagenes
   |- /css
   |- /js
```

Donde `Publico` sería la raíz del servidor web y luego podrías leer las credenciales del fichero en `Aplicacion` o bien usando `require` (si las tienes en PHP) o con [`parse_ini_file`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.parse-ini-file.php) (si las tienes en un .ini, puedes ver un ejemplo en la documentación de PHP).